# PageViewerWebPart strange behaviour

Tags: web-part

i have a custom prop for ContentLink for PageViewerWebPart and the strange thing is that, if i enter `www.yahoo.com` i get this below error:

```
The following file(s) have been blocked by the administrator: /SitePages/www.yahoo.com 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
```

if i enter just `http://www.yahoo.com` its work as expected

and here is my custom webpart prop:

```
        private string _webPartContentLink = null;
 [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("Services")]
        [WebDisplayName("Enter WebPart Content Link")]
        [WebDescription("Enter WebPart Content Link")]
        public string WebPartContentLink 
        {
            get
            {
                if (_webPartContentLink == null)
                {
                    _webPartContentLink = string.Empty;
                }
                return _webPartContentLink;
            }
            set 
                {

                    _webPartContentLink = value;
                }
          }



PageViewerWebPart oWebPart = new PageViewerWebPart();
oWebPart.ContentLink = WebPart.WebPartContentLink.ToString();
Controls.Add(oWebPart);
```

Comment: Unsure but check your alternate access mappings to see if you have an overly-broad rule.

Comment: will you show me the steps how to do that?, i am new to SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation, the ContentLink property can be a Url or file path. 
You can specify the SourceType property of the webpart so that it knows what to expect for the ContentLink.  However, setting the SourceType property will not convert the string in the ContentLink property to a valid url.  In fact, the documentation for the PathPattern, the object type that the SourceType takes, states that "you should provide your own validation code for working with the value".

You could include in the property description for the WebPartContentLink how you want the user to enter the information and then check for this in your code.

```
[WebDescription("Enter WebPart Content Link as http://site Url")]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the message you receive I think SharePoint treats the link as a relative link. With http it seems absolute and works as you expect.